# array showing undefined in variable

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have imorted a module that performs a function on an array of data. When I run the function I get the results in my server but they seem not to be stored in my variable, which comes back undefined. Can someone tell me why my array comes back undefined when I can see the array in my server?

```
 var net = require('net');
 var foo = require('./employeeModule');
 var _ = require('underscore');
 var colors = require('colors/safe');



var server = net.createServer(
  function(socket){
    console.log("Client connection...");

    socket.on('end', function(){
      console.log("Client disconnected...");
    });

//  process data from client
socket.on('data', function(data){
  var command = data.toString();
  var results={};
  console.log("Received Command: " +command);
    if (command == "lookupByLastName Smith")
      {
         function lastName(results)
         {
          var results = foo.lookupByLastName('Smith');
          console.log('These are the results: '+ results)
         }  
      lastName();
      } 

    else if (command == "addEmployee William Smith")
      {
        function addEmp(results)
        {
          var results = foo.addEmployee('William', 'Smith');
          console.log('These are the results: '+ results)
        }
       addEmp();  
       }

    else if (command == "lookupById 4")
      {
        function lookId(results)
        {
          var results = foo.lookupById(4);
          console.log('These are the results: '+ Name)
         }  
      lookId();
      }

    else if (command == "bye")
      client.end();

    else console.log(colors.green("**"+command+" Command not recognized!**"));     

  });     
});


//listent for client connections
 server.listen(1000, function(){
  console.log("Listening for client connections");
 });
```

Comment: What type of value are you getting from this call.    foo.addEmployee('William', 'Smith');

Comment: From the call foo.lookupByLastName('Smith'). I'm getting selected elements from an array. It looks like this [{id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}]. The foo.addEmployee('William', 'Smith') just adds an element to the data take from the imported module.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is wrong with your code:

- `var results={}`: the var `results` is not used.
- you have 3 functions `lastName`, `addEmp` and `lookId`. All are called and nothing is passed, therefore the `results` var is always undefined.
- inside every of those functions you are defining another `var results`, so, nothing is done with the `results` parameter (like overwriting it).
- in `lookId` the var `Name` it is undefined.
- I suppose that you have the parameters hardcoded (`command`s, like `William Smith`, `4` or `Smith`) because it is some type of "test"/learning exercise. I would not recommend you to define the 3 functions inside the callback function (because they are defined every time it is called the callback).

If you want to keep the results do this (following your type of coding):

```
function addEmp(){
  var res = foo.addEmployee('William', 'Smith');
  console.log("There asre the results: " + res);
  return res;
}
results = addEmp(); // now you set the value to results
```

Following more or less what would you do, I would do something like (be careful, I change a bit the type of coding and boundaries/inputs are not controlled):

```
function lastName(surname){
  return foo.lookupByLastName(surname);
}
function addEmp(name, surname){
  return foo.addEmployee(name, surname);
}
// ...

function socketData(data){
  var args = data.toString().split(' '); // assuming space as splitter
  var results;
  var command = args[0];
  switch(command){
  case 'lookupByLastName':
    results = lastName(args[1]);
    break;
  case 'addEmp':
    results = addEmp(args[1], args[2]);
    break;
  default:
    // ...
  }
  // do something with results
}

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
  // ...
  socket.on('data', socketData);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I used for first solution but my res variable is still showing undefined. I redefined the variable to be something like res = 'This result';. This shows me this result but the when I try to store res as                                         res = foo.lookupByLastName('Smith'). Its still returned undefined

Comment: If the `res` variable I defined is undefined it is just because you are returning undefined (or just nothing) from your `foo.addEmployee` function.